# Android UiAutomation not connected! Appium 1.17.1-1

Tags: appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

We are trying to Appium session using the following capability.

```
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "deviceName": "8C4Y14QBGA",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "newCommandTimeout": "1800",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "app": "/process/uploads/20200609131058_nqx3Q.apk",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "platformName": "android",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "platformVersion": "9",
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver] [39m "connectHardwareKeyboard": "true"
```

We are using Java Appium client library to create session with the above capability and we are getting an error while taking a screenshot "UiAutomation not connected!"

Here is the Appium error log.

```
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (3128a38e)][39m Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["3128a38e-d465-4c28-bba5-f9977abd4150"]
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/be4490f0-7be9-48cd-bcae-6a32ed9359c0/screenshot] with no body[35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 500: {"sessionId":"be4490f0-7be9-48cd-bcae-6a32ed9359c0","value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!","stacktrace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!\n\tat android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:1112)\n\tat android.app.UiAutomation.takeScreenshot(UiAutomation.java:709)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.ScreenshotHelper.takeDeviceScreenshot(Unknown Source:169)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.ScreenshotHelper.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source:7)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.ScreenshotHelper.takeScreenshot(Unknown Source:1)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.CaptureScreenshot.safeHandle(Unknown Source:11)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(Unknown Source:0)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(Unknown Source:23)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(Unknown Source:57)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.ht...
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Matched W3C error code 'unknown error' to UnknownError
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (3128a38e)][39m Encountered internal error running command: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (3128a38e)][39m java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Appium will not take screen shots if FLAG_SECURE is enabled for your app for security purposes. Ask the developer to give you an app with the setting disabled.
2. Also, to eliminate the possibility of a problem with the latest appium release 1.17.1-1, please try taking screenshot with appium version v1.16.0 and share your results.

Comment: We could not found Appium 1.16.0 .dmg file on Appium release repo.

Comment: @Mobi_Dev Use the following to install specific version of Appium CLI -

`npm -install -g appium@1.16.0`

But, before this you will have to install `node` as well if not done already. Follow some articles online in order to get this done, example - 
https://www.swtestacademy.com/how-to-install-appium-on-mac/